# GLSL lighting- Attenuation based on a light radius

Tags: opengl, glsl, lighting

So ive been working on lighting, and for the purpose of shadow mapping i did light attenuation based on radius instead of the three attenuation factors (Constant, Linear and quadratic) and, well... It doesn't look very nice near the edges.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H680a.png

It cuts off very rapidly, and the shader code looks like this...

```
#version 330 core

//FragPos = world-space position of current fragment (vec3)
//light.radius is a float.
vec3 distance = (light.pos - FragPos) / light.radius;
float attenuation = 1.0f - dot(distance, distance);
```

So how should i go about making it look not-terrible? For example,
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3QZo.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exist an endless number of possible (not physically based) attenuations. One that I like to use is the one by John Chapman (see [here](http://www.john-chapman.net/content.php?id=3)) that uses a smoothstep interpolation between 0 and the radius of the lightsource:

```
attenuation = smoothstep(light.radius, 0, length(light.pos - FragPos));
```

A possible extension is to introduce an additional exponent (`compression`) that can be used to control how the attenuation should decrease:

```
attenuation = pow(smoothstep(light.radius, 0, length(light.pos - FragPos)), compression);
```

Comment: "error C7623: implicit narrowing of type from "vec3" to "float""

Comment: The third argument of smoothStep is supposed to be a vec3 and the rest floats, correct?

Comment: No: All three arguments are floats. I'll update the answer since I forgot the length function.